# How to make a .NET web app produce logs like the Elastic Beanstalk sample app for .NET on Linux?

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a basic .NET web app and published it on my EB environment (.NET on linux platform). No logs are coming through in log requests or CloudWatch.

I figured I'd look at the sample app from [their docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/tutorials.html) and see how it produces logs, but I can't figure it out. My understanding is that Microsoft doesn't have a write-to-file option out of the box so I expected third-party lib and some config to write to a file. I haven't found any.

I attached a debugger to the dotnet process running their dll on my windows machine and see it's a very basic and minimal ASP.NET app like mine. I can't even find references to the AWSSDK that they included in the code base. All the `using` statements are Microsoft namespaces.

I don't see anything in the `appsettings.json` or `web.config` files that tells it where to write logs to (I think web.config is only used in IIS anyway).

The only thing I see is that they include some log files using `.ebextensions\logging.conf`:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/bundlelogs.d/01-sample-app.conf":
    content: |
      /tmp/sample-app*

  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/01-sample-app.conf":
    content: |
      /tmp/sample-app.log
```

But what is writing these sample-app.log files? The name of the dll to run is DotNetAppSingle.dll. 'sample-app' isn't a term I can find anywhere.

Which brings me to my overall question: How do I produce logs without explicitly writing to a file and a third-party dependency like this app does? What secret magic are they doing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found that the `.ebextensions\logging.conf` wasn't actually doing anything in the sample and is a red herring. `web.config` is entirely unnecessary as well.

The issue this whole time was that I had a `Procfile` in my project with a single line: `worker: dotnet MyApp.dll`. instead of "worker" it must be "web" to create the default web.stdout.log that EB sends to CloudWatch and the bundle of logs. I just took out my Procfile and logging worked as expected.